# get img src from input text id on load modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How to pass input type image (name of pic) to `img src` inside div, when load modal?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="image" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
    <?=l ang( 'image') ?>
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="image" id="pimage" width="300px">
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  var imageSrc = 'http://ricap.pt/encomendas/assets/uploads/' + pimage + '';
  var input = document.getElementById('pimage');
  input.src = imageSrc;
</script>
```

[This show blank div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N4XH.png) and is getting the name of image

Pic url : http://ricap.pt/encomendas/assets/uploads/2774cc3506ee269c379b215d3a1876d5.jpg

Comment: where is the code where you save the img on the server?

Comment: The script is getting the right name of pic from table. The issue is to put him into img src.. Into input text works. I don't wanna to save image. just to visualize

Comment: your assigning `src` to an `input`...

Comment: because this is a editing modal. Inputs are getting data from table. I need show picture too. Only to see
 
Suposing that could be like this                   <img src="assets/uploads/<?php echo $row->image; ?>"  width="100px"></a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979140/html-form-not-changing-url-as-expected/33979311#33979311 You need something to update the variable like an `onKeypress()` event.  If those are php tags use `<?php` the long format - many modern php installations won't run short tags. Be careful to prevent injected script through the text input.  You should then be able to set the `src=`  using `document.getElementById('pimage').src = imageSrc;`

Comment: like this?
 http://jsfiddle.net/webmarkcompt/m39kk5bz/5/ thanks for advice, its running ok but if so I will change them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var imageSrc = 'http://ricap.pt/encomendas/assets/uploads/' + pimage + '';
$('#pimage').parent().append('<img src="'imageSrc'">');
```

Comment: Seems not work
 If i right click show image shows http://ricap.pt/encomendas/assets/uploads/%5Bobject%20HTMLInputElement%5D on url
 
http://s9.postimg.org/e8uxhxk0f/Captura_de_ecra_2015_12_13_a_s_15_52_21.png


/[object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: are you trying to show a picture if you click a button?

Comment: No
The idea is showing when load modal.
It was just to see an example. However, could be an(last) option if work...

Comment: inputs are getting the data from database. 
Using input I can get the name of the image. So, the idea, is try to pass him to img src with some kind of attr.

Inputs are visibible by modal window  http://imgur.com/QVYa5Z7

I could use img scr way the problem is to pass id="pimage" to img src="pimage"

Comment: why aren't you using a simple img tag?

Comment: I prefer if I know how to pass it to img tag...

Please check the html and .js file that get the data http://jsfiddle.net/webmarkcompt/m39kk5bz/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't have a `src=""` in your tag, so you're trying to edit an attribute that isn't there. Add a blank attribute to your code like this:

```
<input src="" type="image" id="pimage" width="300px">
```

`input.src` doesn't add an attribute; it only changes what is already there.

As you mentioned in your comment, you could also do that with PHP like this:

```
<input src="assets/uploads/<?php echo $row->image; ?>" type="image" id="pimage" width="300px">
```

Comment: Ok. Got that

I tried with php but modal is getting text data with jquery and I do not know how to do it with images. 

Is getting an error http://ricap.pt/encomendas/assets/uploads/%5Bobject%20HTMLInputElement%5D if I try to visualize (blank) image

I also tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/cBJXn/4/ but the question is how to insert data value in input text value